# pygame stopwatch and defining a box

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game about robbery , it sounds awesome :) But I have problem.
My player can move left and right(that's fine), and on end of the room is a safe,But how could I alert pygame that I am in the area of the same.
And here is another problem, When i am in, (I put that if x>player >= x_safe:(which is really bad solution),
is that I need to be in area of safe for 3 seconds, you will see in code below that i put

```
if x>player >= x_safe:
    now = time.time()
    unlocked = now + 3
    if unlocked < now: # WHICH WILL NEVER HAPPEN BECOUSE OF WHILE LOOP
```

Here is code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Breaking in")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
#bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load("standing.png")
safe = pygame.image.load("sef.png")
right = False
left = False
walkCount = 0


playerSkin = pygame.image.load("player.png")
guardSkin = pygame.image.load("guard.png")
#guardSkin_flip = pygame.image.load("guard_fliped.png")
#gajbaImg = pygame.image.load("gajba.png")
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
        self.image = pygame.image.load("background.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location


def text_objects(text,font):
    textSurface = font.render(text,True,black)
    return textSurface,textSurface.get_rect()

def sefplace(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(safe,(x,y))
#560,336
def message_dispaly(text,size):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",size)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text,largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf,TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()
#224,365

def guard(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(guardSkin,(x,y))


def game_loop():
    global walkCount
    global left
    global right
    safe_width = 50
    safe_height = 51
    sef_x = 560
    sef_y = 300
    player_width = 64
    player_height = 64


    BackGround = Background("background.png",[0,0])
    guard_range = 100
    x_player = (20)
    y_player = (display_height/2)
    x_guard = (650)
    y_guard = (display_height/2)
    x_change = 0
    guard_speed = 1.3
    catched = False
    while not catched:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                catched = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -2.3
                    left = True
                    right = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 2.3
                    left = False
                    right = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    right = False
                    left = False
                    walkCount = 0
                    x_change = 0

        #458 max
        x_guard -= guard_speed
        if x_guard < 499:
            guard_speed *= -1
            guardSkin = pygame.image.load("guard_fliped.png")
        elif x_guard > 750:
            guard_speed *= -1

        if x_player < 5:
            x_player = 5
        #if x_player > x_guard - guard_range:
            #message_dispaly("You got Catched !",65)

        gameDisplay.fill([255,255,255])
        gameDisplay.blit(BackGround.image,BackGround.rect)
        sefplace(sef_x,sef_y)
        #guard(x_guard,y_guard)

        if left:
            gameDisplay.blit(walkLeft[walkCount%3],(x_player,y_player))
            walkCount += 1
        elif right:
            gameDisplay.blit(walkRight[walkCount%3],(x_player,y_player))
            walkCount += 1
        else:
            gameDisplay.blit(char,(x_player,y_player))
        x_player += x_change
        x_player += x_change
        if x_player >= sef_x and x_player:
            print("upali smo")
            #now = time.time()
            #unlocked = now + 4
            #print("Ovo je sada " + str(now))
            #print("Ovo je otkljucano " + str(unlocked))
            #if unlocked < now:
                #message_dispaly("Otkljucano",50)








        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(27)
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: This code has an error here: `if x_player >= sef_x and x_player !`. It is probaly just a copy-paste error, so what belongs there?

Comment: That was type error.... and that was not my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a box with `pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)`.

A simple stopwatch can be represented with a font object and a time variable.

```
time = 0
dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000

# In the loop

time += dt
myFont.render(str(round(time, 1)), True, (255, 255, 255))

screen.blit(myFont, (0, 0))
```

dt stands for delta time, a good way to convert fps to actual seconds.

If you wanted to check if the time was three while colliding, heres some code

```
if myRect.collidepoint(player.pos.x, player.pos.y):
    time += dt
    if time >= 3:
        # Do Stuff
```

Comment: No, I added a proper example.

Comment: Have you added the dt and time variables? What is the error message, you are being extremely hard to work with.

Comment: Will you help or not?

Comment: Yes. As long as you dont edit my post to negate my opinion. You are being stubborn.